# AWT FileDialog filename copy/paste keystrokes?

Tags: java, macos, awt

I don't normally write java GUI apps, but I needed a simple utility and I managed to write it using Swing and AWT. The utility needs to open and save files, and it's mainly used on Macos. [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-SW1) using AWT's `FileDialog` instead of the Swing file chooser because `FileDialog` acts more like the native Macos file dialog. So that's what I did.

The finished utility works fine, except for one thing that I haven't been able to resolve. The dialog for saving a file includes a text box to type in a filename. Right-clicking on the text box reveals a menu with copy and paste options. But the associated keystrokes (Cmd-C, Cmd-V) don't do anything.

The following program demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Scratch extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton saveButton;
    FileDialog fd;

    public Scratch(Frame aFrame) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        fd = new FileDialog(aFrame, "Save", FileDialog.SAVE);
        saveButton = new JButton("Save a File...");
        saveButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(saveButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            fd.setVisible(true);
            String file = fd.getFile();
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scratch");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Scratch(frame));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you run it it opens a window with a save button. Clicking the button opens a FileDialog with a "Save as" field. You can type into the field, and you can right-click on the field and select "copy" or "paste" from the popup menu. But you can't use Cmd-V to paste into the field--there don't seem to be any keystrokes bound to the copy or paste actions.

Is there a straightforward way to bind keystrokes to the filename box inside the `FileDialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWT FileDialog (at least under java 8 on MacOS) ends up calling [CFileDialog. nativeRunFileDialog()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/macosx/classes/sun/lwawt/macosx/CFileDialog.java) to display the actual dialog. The parameters passed to this method don't appear to include anything that could be used to attach keystrokes to the save dialog's filename field.

My conclusion is that there's no reasonable way to alter the FileDialog to add keystrokes to the save option. I've reverted to the Swing JFileChooser in the application.